# How to track unregistered users in my webshop?

Tags: php, laravel, webshop

I'm currently working on a webshop.
I use JWT for Authentication and I was wondering if JWT has a method which allows you to track guests on your site?

If JWT doesn't have that kind of a functionality, than how can I track a unregistered guest in my website?

Br

Comment: Google Analytics or similar?

Comment: I used Google Analytics in the past, but i don't think that going to work in that case. I rather need some kind of a JWT like solution.

Comment: Just to check, what is your understanding when you say JWT? And why do you think GA wouldn't work?

Comment: You mean track user's like with a cookie?

Comment: In my understanding JWT is an information transfer between two parties, which helps indentifing the user

Comment: With JWT like, i meant someting straight forward solution, where after an action is triggered(guest visited a site or the user registered...) a token is created and I can use that token later for identification.

Comment: Personally I think you're trying to force JWT to be something that it's not. You want to track users in your site, use tools that were designed and built to do exactly that.

Comment: You're quite literally describing a cookie.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, cookie could be a way to go. Just to clarify things, JWT is not capable of tracking unregistered users?